# sending endsession request to identityserver throws error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, openid-connect, identityserver3, asp.net-authentication

I have a ASP.NET MVC application with framework 4.7.2. The application is configured to use IdentityServer3 using OpenIDConnect. When user clicks on Logout button the following code is invoked

**Action Method** The logout action method get invoked first.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        Session.Clear();
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
        }            
        return Redirect("/");
    }
```

In Owin `Startup.cs` i have configured OpenIDConnect. The `RedirectToIdentityProvider` event fires next.
Here, I am setting `IdTokenHint` when RequestType is Logout.

```
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                LoginPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/Home"),
                SlidingExpiration = true,
                ExpireTimeSpan = GetCookieExpiration()
            };

        var openIdOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["id:Authority"],
            Scope = "openid email profile",
            ClientId = "My ClientId",
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:58641/Home",
            ResponseType = "id_token",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            UseTokenLifetime = false,

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                {
                    //code here removed for brevity 

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },

                RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                {
                    if (context.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                    {
                        var idTokenHint = context.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token").Value;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint;
                        
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        };

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(openIdOptions);

        MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;            
    }
```

I fiddler i see it makes a call to

`/identity/connect/endsession?id_token_hint= xxxxxxxx` However, the HTTP Verb its using
is `OPTIONS`. So the IdentityServer throws error `The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'`

[image]

Not sure what i am missing Here.

**Edit 1**

In browser console i see the following error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://localhost:44300/identity/connect/endsession?id_token_hint=xxxxxxx'
> (redirected from 'http://localhost:58641/account/logout') from origin
> 'http://localhost:58641' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

**Edit 2**
I have another ASP.NET Application that has the same logout code. But its making `GET` request to endsession.

Comment: Have you changed the web.config file in the IdServer to allow OPTIONS method? Should have an entry like: <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD" />

Comment: I think that would be a hack. The client should not not use `OPTIONS` verb in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

When you see the use of **OPTIONS** and the request contains the origin header, then that is a **CORS preflight request.** This is an extra security request that occurs when a JavaScript client tries to make an AJAX request to an API.

Is this intended to trigger the endsession from JavaScript? if so, you need for that client in identityServer set:

```
AllowedCorsOrigins =
{
    "https://localhost:xxxxx"
},
```

This is set per client in IdentityServer.